# How do I extract just the epsg code for a raster using Terra package in r

Tags: terra

First i am a newbie to Terra and not a programmer. Am really only a novice in r so please forgive me if this is a simple task.

I would like to be able to compare the projections of a raster file to a set of shapefiles and if they do not match reproject the shapefiles to match the raster. I thought the best way to do this would be to compare the epsg codes of each of the files. The crs function provides the complete description of the projection but I would like to just return the epsg part of that description. Is there a way to do this?

As a novice I have sort of guessed a few things but found nothing worked. I even tried asking ChatGPT but it seems to think there is an epsg() function which i do not think exists or does not exist anymore

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps have another look at `?crs`. You can do

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
crs(r, describe=T)
#    name authority code  area             extent
#1 WGS 84      EPSG 4326 World -180, 180, 90, -90
```

Comparing coordinate reference systems (CRS) is tricky.
Comparing EPSG codes is not a good general solution as only a fraction of all CRSs definitions have an EPSG code (the number of CRSs is infinite).

Perhaps `terra::same.crs` is better suited to your needs. But I suspect that function is also prone to returning false negatives.

```
same.crs(r, "+proj=longlat")
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Robert. I have come up with a solution which will ensure all the  rasters are in the same projection prior to the analysis in R so there will be no longer a need to do a comparison in R

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to change the projection of rasters, because it deteriorates the data quality. You should project the vector data instead, if applicable.